# Can we load Autocomplete TextView in android with some Specific text?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Hi i am new to android technology. I am having an autocomplete textview. Its working fine.

**My doubt**

Can we load with  some default text in  autocomplete textview?

Comment: Some specific text ??? Do you mean some default values in the autoComplete View ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 yes some default text.

Comment: Do you mean text hint?

Comment: `I am having an autocomplete textview. Its working fine.` How it is working fine if it is not loaded with the text ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain While typing a text , it showing a available list as like drop down menu

Comment: it is intended to show a list while typing.

Comment: yeah.. i need to set a default text in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);


 private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
     "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
 };
```

And when you want to update your adapter, you clear these values and update the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged().

Source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
android:text="some text"
```

to your `Textview` xml

Answer (score 0):

What i can understand is that you want some text to be shown as the default text in the AutoCompleteTextView. 
For that you can simply use

```
 android:text="your text to appear as default"
```